# How did Soviet-influenced countries cope with US sanctions during the cold war?

Tags: united-states, sanctions

The USA has been using economic sanctions as a very effective tool.

How effectively did it work during the Cold War?

How did Soviet-influenced countries cope with US sanctions during the cold war?

Comment: Factors to consider:  1) Warsaw Pact had manufacturing capacity (good/bad) in many fields they now only source from West - ex: commercial jets  2) modern gear relies on *lots* of chips 3) Cold War sanctions were "narrower", i.e. no weapon exports/no high tech.  Today's sanctions are "kitchen sink" 4) 40/50s tech had probably a smaller gap and sanctions gradually made their mark - i.e. USSR had decades to adjust, not months.  *And decades to lose ground*, which it, did till collapse 5) USSR had extensive covert acquisition operations.  Russia does too.  Good Q, looking fwd to learning from As.

Comment: Since it all would've happened 30+ years ago, this might be a better question for the History SE site.

Comment: @Giter Except that the West is pursuing such a policy right now - at a not inconsiderable cost - with a country whose leadership wants to re-USSR itself.  So it might be interesting to see how that worked in the past.  The results of past sanction regimes - Lybia, South Africa, Iran - were debatable, apparently, but then again it is one way, and far from the worst, to pressure Russia to behave itself.

Comment: Ultimately not well, I'd say, since communism collapsed in all of them. You also have to remember that due to ideology many regimes of the kind you ask about tried *not* to have much econ relations with  the evil capitalists. So there were self-imposed sanctions as well.

Comment: There were also significant differences between these countries in term of autarky/craziness of their leaders. Just compare Albania with Yugoslavia for instance.

Comment: This might be better in the History.SE.